# C# - Change Label Text in opened Form from another Class

Tags: c#, forms, call, invoke

I am coding a Program in C# using WinForms which has language Support, means a user can for example change the Program Language from English to German.

Now I have `Form1` with `Label1` and a `Class1`.

`Class1` has a public void method named `Translate()` and it should translate the text of the `Label1`.
It does that by executing `Translate()` at the `Form1` Load Event but which doesn't work for me.

I tried it with the following code in `Form1`:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Class1(Translate());
    }
```

Code in `Class1`:

```
 public void Translate()
    {
        if (Language.Equals(1))
        {
            new Form1().Label1.Text = "English Translated Text";
        }
        else if(Language.Equals(2))
        {
            new Form1().Label1.Text = "German Translated Text";
        }
    }
```

It probably doesn't work since It changes the Text Label at a new Form instead of changing it on the already opened form but I don't know how to make it work using the code that I already have.

Comment: Firstly, this is not the correct approach. But, if you want it to change this way, pass the form1 instance to the Translate method. You can use "this" to get the current form. Read some text here and on other places regarding Localisation in WinForms apps. You will get more insight how that should work. If you want this solution to work - read about passing form instance...

Comment: Why just use your `Form1` to write the those codes instead of using a separate class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, pass the Form via `this`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    c1.Translate(this));
}
```

In `Translate()`:

```
public void Translate(Form1 f1)
{
    if (Language.Equals(1))
    {
        f1.Label1.Text = "English Translated Text";
    }
    else if(Language.Equals(2))
    {
        f1.Label1.Text = "German Translated Text";
    }
}
```

*This assumes, however, that `Label1` is publicly accessible on Form1.  Controls are not publicly accessible by default.  To fix this, change the `Modifiers` property of `Label` to public.

But the real solution lies in implementing [Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/).